# Required user for ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

Tags: c#, .net, threadpool

Maybe this question doesn't go here....

I am using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` to write a folder/file, my problem is when it tries to write I got `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

So I changed the directory to grant everyone to write and it works.

But I don't want to grant everyone to write. It seems is a different user/group that the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` uses than the main thread.

What user should it be?

Comment: Is this a program running in a asp.net website? Also what happens if you write with the main thread?

Comment: Correct, webaplication c# framework 4.0. The main thread, I mean the proccess in the aspx, write without any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is a IIS application the user you have to grant rights to is [the user the application pool runs under](https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities).

Your main thread is likey impersonating the user that the request is for. The background work item is nolonger associated with the user.

PS: using ThreadPool.QueueBackgroundWorkItem in IIS is [a very bad idea](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html), you need to use a more appropriate tool for background work in IIS.

Comment: Interesting answer! But it raises many questions for me. **1.** Could it be that the issue happens *only* with `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` precisely because it's not really recommended / supported in ASP.NET? Would impersonation also be an issue with the TPL (i.e. `Task.StartNew`) **2.** even though it's probably built on top of `ThreadPool`? **3.** If all async stuff in ASP.NET is a bad idea, it would be weird for ASP.NET to have async facilities (such as asynchronous HTTP handlers) and people would've experienced weird issues like the OP's all the time when using the TPL...?

Comment: Starting background threads on IIS is not normally done, you are already on a thread pool thread, and if you use the async features like async/await the context flows with the user. See this article for more info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa954062.aspx

Comment: What should it be that appropiate tool for IIS?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Thanks for the link. One thing I still don't understand though: what does it mean that the "context flows with the user" with the TPL?

Comment: @Jamo see the 2nd link in my answer.

Comment: @stakx I was cut off. Typing on my phone. A better phrasing would be "in async await the context flows though the await across threads, including the security identity of the user"

Comment: Here is some more useful reading about async context flow, read the related articles mentioned at the start too. http://vegetarianprogrammer.blogspot.com/2012/12/understanding-synchronizationcontext-in.html?m=1